# Service worker : fetch event listener is never triggered by HTTP GET requests to an API on Angular 7

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I used `@angular/service-worker` module to generate a service-worker to cache all static assets for my Angular 7 app and it works well (in network tab on chrome dev tools, these files are tagged as `from ServiceWorker`).

What I am trying to do is adding cache support (and background sync) to data got from an external API. I know that `@angular/service-worker` module supports `dataGroups` type of assets but I would like to do something more complicated : serving cache data first then fetch data through network, update the cache and finally return a second, fresher response. This idea is described in the offline cookbook : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network
So I need to add a custom SW coexisting with the one generated by Angular. Problem is my `fetch` event listener is never fired.

I register my service worker :
`ServiceWorkerModule.register('../sw.js', { enabled: environment.production }),` in app.module.ts.

sw.js file imports ngsw-worker.js (which is generated by Angular) :

```
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
importScripts('./sw-custom.js');
```

Then, `sw-custom.js` is adding two events listener on `install` and `fetch` :

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    try {
        console.log('typeof System in install', typeof System);
    } catch(e){}

    console.log('caching');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function(cache) {
            console.log('caching - getting');
            return;
        }).catch(function(error){ console.log('error', error) })
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log('Hello service worker');
    if (event.request.method !== 'GET') return;
    const request = event.request.clone();
    // Do stuff
    event.respondWith(fetch(request));
  });
```

The listener on `install` event is executed, but not the `fetch` one and I can't understand why.

Comment: Have you found out its solution, yet? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're importing Angular `ngsw-worker.js` first, it contains it's own listeners that can prevent your listener from being executed.

Try changing the import order like this:

```
importScripts('./sw-custom.js');
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
```

Also, you may need to prevent angular generated listeners to run by stopping the event propagation avoiding things like duplicate fetches:

```
  self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log('Hello service worker');
    if (event.request.method !== 'GET') return;
    const request = event.request.clone();
    // Do stuff
    event.respondWith(fetch(request));

    // stop propagation to Angular Service Worker if we need
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

At inspection tab, head over to Application>Service Workers, click on 
[unregister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmrYc.png) then ctrl-F5 for two times, first refresh is for service workers to register itself, second refresh is for the service worker to listener to your fetch event. Your code is tested working on my Angular 6 project.